# Data Binding WPF and vb

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding, charts

I have a problem with data binding using WPF and vb.net. Actually, I tried it using WPF(xaml) and C# and it worked very well. However, when I want to build it using vb.net I faced a problem that data is empty and nothing is shown. Therefore, I am pretty sure, it is related to data binding between WPF and VB.net. I will appreciate it if someone can figure out the error I did during coding. Thanks in advance.
The VB.net Code :

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Controls
Imports System.IO


Namespace chartTest
    Public Class MainWindow
        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()

            Dim Errors As New TestPageViewModel()
            Errors = Me.DataContext
        End Sub

        Public Class TestPageViewModel
            Public m_Errors As ObservableCollection(Of DataChart)
            Public Property Errors() As ObservableCollection(Of DataChart)
                Get
                    Return m_Errors
                End Get
                Private Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of DataChart))
                    m_Errors = value
                End Set
            End Property



            Public Sub addDataChart()
                Errors = New ObservableCollection(Of DataChart)()
                Errors.Add(New DataChart() With { _
                     .Category = "Globalization", _
                     .Number = 75 _
                })

                Errors.Add(New DataChart() With { _
                     .Category = "Features", _
                     .Number = 2 _
                })

                Errors.Add(New DataChart() With { _
                     .Category = "ContentTypes", _
                     .Number = 12 _
                })

                Errors.Add(New DataChart() With { _
                     .Category = "Correctness", _
                     .Number = 83 _
                })

                Errors.Add(New DataChart() With { _
                     .Category = "Best Practices", _
                     .Number = 29 _
                })

            End Sub

            Private m_selectedItem As Object = Nothing
            Public Property SelectedItem() As Object
                Get
                    Return m_selectedItem
                End Get
                Set(value As Object)
                    m_selectedItem = value
                End Set
            End Property
        End Class

        ' class which represent a data point in the chart
        Public Class DataChart
            Private m_Category As String
            Public Property Category() As String
                Get
                    Return m_Category
                End Get
                Set(value As String)
                    m_Category = value
                End Set
            End Property

            Private m_Number As Integer
            Public Property Number() As Integer
                Get
                    Return m_Number
                End Get
                Set(value As Integer)
                    m_Number = value
                End Set
            End Property

        End Class
    End Class
End Namespace
```

The XAML code is as follow:

```
<Window x:Class="chartTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:chartTest.chartTest"
        >
    <Window.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="73*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <chart:PieChart

        ChartTitle="Minimal Pie Chart"
        ChartSubTitle="Chart with fixed width and height"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
            <chart:PieChart.Series>
                <chart:ChartSeries
                SeriesTitle="Errors"
                DisplayMember="Category"
                ValueMember="Number"
                Width="400"
                Height="400"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}"/>

            </chart:PieChart.Series>
        </chart:PieChart>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Errors = Me.DataContext
```

This Should be:

```
Me.DataContext = Errors
```

You set Errors to DataContext which is *Nothing* at programm start.

Comment: I have changed it, but I still have an empty chart. Which means data binding is not correctly called from the xaml. Any other suggestions !!